# How can automate generating update site?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho

In our project many eclipse plugins are prepared. I want use tycho to build eclipse plugins automatically. But while executing "mvn install" in an update site project tycho can not find required features.  Is there anything wrong??

```
My Update site   ---> packaging : eclipse-update-site 
My feature       ---> packaging : eclipse-feature 
my plugin        ---> packaging : eclipse-plugin
```

How can i use tycho to install my plugin and feature in my target platform (eclipse) ??

Answer (score 2):

A repository is generated when you create a project with the following packaging as part of a multimodule build.

```
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
```

You can then reference it in Eclipse by pointing to the target/repository directory.  As for deployment, there is no automated way of deploying that is provided by Tycho.  Everything I have found so far involves the use of antrun or some other non-maven integrated way or even some unofficial plugin.

It's not like I haven't reported it either:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401078
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353764

Tycho appears to favor doing things explicitly rather than providing sensible defaults like the Maven core.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`p2.generator`** task described in [Equinox p2 Metadata Generator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Metadata_Generator) page.

It will allow you :

- to generate metadata for a folder containing bundles and features (`-source` argument)
- to generate metadata for a traditional Eclipse update site (`-updateSite` argument)
- to generate metadata for an existing Eclipse application that does not contain p2 metadata (`-config` argument)

So in your case, I suspect your site lack the necessary metadata to be correctly installed in the eclipse target platform.

Comment: The p2 metadata generator is deprecated and now points to Publisher.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher  However, I wasn't able to find the equivalent target so I didn't update the answer.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano good to know. In the meantime, +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform) of the build. The target platform is where Tycho looks for plug-ins and features that are referenced by your own artifacts.

It is not possible to automatically install plug-ins built by Tycho into your Eclipse. However you can build a p2 repository (aka update site) with Tycho and use it as source for the "install new software" wizard.